# OCaml ctypes idiomatic way to deal with out parameters

Tags: ocaml

I'm writing OCaml wrappers for a few C functions that use the out-parameter idiom and return an error code. I've been wrapping them by allocating a C array on the OCaml side using `Ctypes.allocate_n`. And then copying the contents out into an OCaml type.

I feel like I'm hacking around a problem that `Ctypes` or some other module already solves in another way, here's an example.

`gethostname(2)` has the following type:

```
int gethostname(char *name, size_t len);
```

Here's `out_parameter.mli` for the wrapped `gethostname` function.

```
val gethostname : int -> [> `Ok of string | `Error of int];;
```

Here's the implementation

```
open Core.Std;;
let (@->) = Ctypes.(@->);;
let returning = Ctypes.returning;;
open Foreign;;

let gethostname size =
  let size' = Unsigned.Size_t.of_int size in
  let c_gethostname =
    foreign "gethostname" (Ctypes.ptr Ctypes.char @-> Ctypes.size_t @-> returning Ctypes.int) in
  let buf = Ctypes.allocate_n Ctypes.char ~count:size in
  let err = c_gethostname buf size' in
  match err with
  | 0 -> (
    `Ok (Ctypes.string_from_ptr buf ~length:size)
    )
  | _ -> `Error err;;

let main () =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (match gethostname 1000 with
  | `Ok hostname -> hostname
  | `Error _ -> "error getting hostname");;

let () = main ();;
```

And for the sake of compeleteness I compiled `out_parameter.native` with this command.

```
$ corebuild -pkg ctypes.foreign out_parameter.native
```

The code does work and returns the hostname, with trailing null bytes stripped.

```
$ ./out_parameter.native
MY-HOSTNAME

$ ./out_parameter.native | sed -e 's/\x0/@/g'
MY-HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your code works and is idiomatic. There are two ways to represent errors:

- you can throw an exception.
- you can use a result type. If you do that, I would recommend using the "new" builtin `result` type (that has been backported for older versions of OCaml in the [result](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/result/) package).

Generally speaking, you are responsible for writing code that supports that error convention (the `match err` part in your code). It is often possible to write a couple combinators to reduce the boilerplate.

However, there are a couple shortcuts provided by `ctypes` if you use `Cstubs` (code generation):

- [`errno_policy`](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/blob/774cc6303775c01962e14ecc821a67c92a2b161e/src/cstubs/cstubs.mli#L101-L131) can implement libc's `errno` convention.
- [`concurrency_policy`](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/blob/774cc6303775c01962e14ecc821a67c92a2b161e/src/cstubs/cstubs.mli#L133-L189) can tune the C code so that it correspond to a given concurrency model (lwt, etc). This is not about error conventions, but is somewhat related.

If you stick to `Foreign` (which makes your build system simpler than `Cstubs`), then I'd recommend doing it by hand, or extracting a couple combinators if you have a lot of similar functions.